# How to solve $\frac{3\vert x\vert }{\vert x\vert -2}<\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality

I'm having difficulties on how to start off this question: $
\frac{3\vert x\vert }{\vert x\vert -2}<\frac{3}{2}$

I'm tempted to square both sides but I don't think it will help in
simplifying the inequality. In short, I have no idea where to start and
was wondering if anyone could help

Comment: Just multiply by $|x|-2$ and remember that when you multiply an inequality by a  negative number the inequality sign changes.

Comment: Can you solve $\dfrac{3t}{t - 2} < \dfrac{3}{2}$?

Comment: You can consider two cases: $x \ge 0$ and $x<0$ to get rid of the absolute value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\frac {3|x|}{|x|-2}-\frac 32<0$$
So, $$\frac {6|x|-3(|x|-2)}{2(|x|-2)}<0$$
So, $$\frac {|x|+2}{|x|-2}<0$$
So, $|x|\in (-2,2)$

Since $|x|>0$, we get:
$$|x|<2$$ as our final condition. This means:
$$x \in (-2,2)$$

Comment: This method makes it much more simpler than I thought, thanks!